# Customize Range slider in bootstrap to show dots or markers on possible points

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, rangeslider

`<input class="custom-range" type="range" min="-3" max="3" default="0" step="1">`

I want to show dots or any marker on each possible point to make it user friendly.

It is currently like this
[custom range (bootstrap 4)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbL2B.png) but I want something like this [custom range with markers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ol8Lx.png). sorry for rough drawing. hope you get my point. Thanks